# Setting Query Parameter on MongoHQ beta API

Tags: mongodb, curl, mongohq

I'm using the beta api on **MongoHQ.com** to query a database I set up earlier this week.

I can retrieve the list of databases on my account, the collections in each database and the documents in each collection using the basic URLs.

However, when I try to set a query, limit, fields, etc parameter, it's returning a **404** error.

This is the `curl` command I'm using:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/<deployment id>/<database name>/collections/<collection name>/documents?query={"name": "Name"}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: api-key <API KEY>'
```

According to the documentation on the site here - https://docs.mongohq.com/mongohq-api-beta/mongodb-documents.html - the query has to be a "URL encoded MongoDB Extended JSON document". Unfortunately there are no examples of this.

How would I convert the query document above to a URL encoded one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl` to urlencode your query like this:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/<deployment id>/<database name>/collections/<collection name>/documents' \ 
  -G --data-urlencode 'query={"name": "Name"}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: api-key <API KEY>'
```

If you use operators like e.g. `$gt`, be sure to put double quotes around them:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://beta-api.mongohq.com/mongo/<deployment id>/<database name>/collections/<collection name>/documents' \ 
  -G --data-urlencode 'query={"value": { "$gt" : 10}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: api-key <API KEY>'
```

Comment: that's perfect! works exactly as I want it to! Thanks, it was killing me!